# Looking for a book about a group of psychics, one locked in a completely dark cell

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, telepathy

It's about this group of psychics. Mostly what I remember is the main male character (or one of them) is locked in a cell. Aforementioned cell is completely dark, and the young man is locked in there for quite a while, when he notices a white rope or ladder dangling above him.

He follows the rope or ladder up to a web of similar constructs. While there he sees a female that he recognizes down someone else's thread or ladder, and scurries down to enter this person's mind. When he does, the female recognizes him. However, I'm pretty sure he ends up back in his cell instead of escaping.

Comment: Hehe, "completely dark" and "notices a white rope or ladder".

Comment: Psychics in prison isn't much to go on. Can you remember why they're jailed, who put them there, any character names, any notable phrases, how the book ended, etc?

Comment: Honestly, no. This is literally the only thing I can remember about the book. Though I think it was either the government, or some faction of psychic warriors. I'm not too sure though. I'm sorry. I know this isn't very helpful.